# How to define a condition on boolean operation based on returned result of previous file

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

Apologies if this question has already been asked, but I have not found a satisfactory answer.

I have a series of files that I wish to test using a boolean operation. If a file meets a condition, the code returns "True"; if not, returns "False". My code iterates over every file within a specified directory and then returns the sum of all files that have met the condition.

Some explanatory code below:

```
for roots, dirs, filenames in os.walk(in_dir):
    for f in filenames:
        sum_values = (np.max(array) - np.mean(array))
        boolean = np.greater_equal(sum_values, 100)
        print boolean
```

My question is, that I would like to provide an additional condition, such that when testing a file, if the previous file returns value "True", then the file automatically returns "False". If the previous file returns "False", then the condition with boolean result works as normal. For example:

```
file        boolean    boolean_with_condition
001         True       True
002         True       False
003         False      False
004         True       True
005         False      False
006         False      False
```

I hope that makes sense. I wish the `boolean_with_condition` value for row `n` to be dependent on the `boolean` values for rows `n` and `n-1`. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: store the previous result in a variable, if its true, current result is false, else normal logic then previous result = current result

Answer (score 0):

```
for roots, dirs, filenames in os.walk(in_dir):
    previous = False
    for f in filenames:
        sum_values = (np.max(array) - np.mean(array))
        boolean = np.greater_equal(sum_values, 100) and (not previous)
        print boolean 
        previous = boolean
```

Comment: Hi, is that a recursive argument? You´ve defined `boolean` by two terms, a numpy `greater_equal` argument, and `not previous` - but then `previous` is later defined in terms of `boolean`. Would this not lead to a circular argument?

Comment: @ailsa_naismith What I'm doing with `boolean = np.greater_equal(sum_values, 100) and (not previous)` is equivalent to `if previous: boolean = False; else: boolean = np.greater_equal(sum_values, 100)`